# Owner of a data directory became 'Debian-exim' on 16.04.3 LTS

Tags: server, permissions

I'm running an Ubuntu server 16.04.3 LTS, mainly for file sharing purposes within the household. Yesterday my wife couldn't write to a shared folder (from here iMac). When I checked the permissions of that shared folder on the server, the owner was `Debian-exim`. I changed it back and now everything is fine again. How is it possible that `Debian-exim` became the owner of that folder in the first place? I never did it and haven't changed anything to the system recently.

I have attached a screenshot of the ownership before and after my correction.

Very strange, I hope someone has an idea what could have happened.

```
ralph@NAS:~$ sudo nano /etc/samba/smb.conf
[sudo] password for ralph:
ralph@NAS:~$ cd /mnt/main1
ralph@NAS:/mnt/main1$ ls -la
total 291956
drwxrwxr-x  9 ralph       users      4096 Feb  7 00:15 .
drwxr-xr-x  8 root        root       4096 Jan 20 11:09 ..
drwxr-s--- 10 ralph       users      4096 Jan 30 20:36 data
drwxrwsr-x 22 root        users      4096 Jan 30 20:01 fotoalbum
drwxr-sr-x  6 ralph       users      4096 Aug 25 16:02 homevideos
drwxrwxr-x  2 root        users     16384 Jun 20  2017 lost+found
drwxr-s--- 12 Debian-exim users      4096 Jan  9 08:51 affecteddir
drwxr-sr-x 18 ralph       users      4096 Aug 25 19:07 mediacards
-rw-------  1 root        root  298910866 Feb  7 00:15 snapraid.content
-rw-------  1 ralph       ralph         0 Feb  7 00:15 snapraid.content.lock
drwxr-xr-x  2 root        root       4096 Feb  4 13:27 temp
ralph@NAS:/mnt/main1$ sudo chown liesbeth:users /mnt/main1/affecteddir -R
ralph@NAS:/mnt/main1$ sudo chmod 750 /mnt/main1/affecteddir -R
ralph@NAS:/mnt/main1$ ls -la
total 291956
drwxrwxr-x  9 ralph    users      4096 Feb  7 00:15 .
drwxr-xr-x  8 root     root       4096 Jan 20 11:09 ..
drwxr-s--- 10 ralph    users      4096 Jan 30 20:36 data
drwxrwsr-x 22 root     users      4096 Jan 30 20:01 fotoalbum
drwxr-sr-x  6 ralph    users      4096 Aug 25 16:02 homevideos
drwxrwxr-x  2 root     users     16384 Jun 20  2017 lost+found
drwxr-s--- 12 liesbeth users      4096 Jan  9 08:51 affecteddir
drwxr-sr-x 18 ralph    users      4096 Aug 25 19:07 mediacards
-rw-------  1 root     root  298910866 Feb  7 00:15 snapraid.content
-rw-------  1 ralph    ralph         0 Feb  7 00:15 snapraid.content.lock
drwxr-xr-x  2 root     root       4096 Feb  4 13:27 temp
ralph@NAS:/mnt/main1$ sudo service smbd restart

ralph@NAS:/mnt/main2$ df -h
Filesystem              Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev                    7.7G     0  7.7G   0% /dev
tmpfs                   1.6G  9.5M  1.6G   1% /run
/dev/sda1               132G  3.1G  122G   3% /
tmpfs                   7.7G     0  7.7G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs                   5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
tmpfs                   7.7G     0  7.7G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/sde1               3.6T  2.2T  1.5T  60% /mnt/camera
tmpfs                   1.6G     0  1.6G   0% /run/user/1000
/dev/mapper/main1-enc   3.6T  1.9T  1.6T  55% /mnt/main1
/dev/mapper/main2-enc   3.6T  2.4T  1.1T  70% /mnt/main2
/dev/mapper/parity-enc  3.6T  2.5T  984G  72% /mnt/parity
192.168.1.12:/mnt/usb   4.6T  3.3T  1.1T  77% /mnt/usb5tb
```

Comment: @Melebius: thanks. I edited the question. The main reason I used an image was that I did not want some folder names appear in search engines. I renamed them now in de code section.

Comment: Using an image is not a good solution anyway since there is OCR software out there and [search engines _do_ use it](https://www.techwyse.com/blog/search-engine-optimization/google-reads-text-in-images/). Replacing the names is a much better way.